# How to set border for border for grid row?

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, grid, row

I have used Grid and set four rows:

```
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="654*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="42*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="17*" />
            <RowDefinition Height="0*" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

At grid there are 3 components:

1st is canvas for regular chart, 2nd is canvas for chart that shows only X axis and 3rd is one scroll bar.

I set this:

```
<Canvas  Name="canvas1" Grid.Row="0"></Canvas>
<Canvas  Name="canvas2" Grid.Row ="1"></Canvas>
<ScrollBar  Name="scrollBarX" Grid.Row ="2" Orientation="Horizontal"   
        ValueChanged="scrollBarX_ValueChanged" LargeChange="0.1" 
        Height="17" VerticalAlignment="Top" />
```

Problem is that 2nd canvas extends over row which is reserved for scroll bar.

[image]
Do you know where is problem?

Comment: Try setting `ClipToBounds="True"` on 2nd `Canvas` and see if it helps

Answer (score 0):

Set the **Height** of your 2nd Row to **Auto**
    
        
        
        ...